# Span generators in parametric vector form

Tags: linear-algebra

I am learning about spans and representing solution sets of martices using them. However, I still am not sure how to properly transform them. For example, I have a solution set that can be described as:
$$\begin{pmatrix}-58 \\\ -101 \\\ 9 \\\ 0\end{pmatrix}+Span\Biggl\{\begin{pmatrix}-13 \\\ -25 \\\ 2 \\\ 1\end{pmatrix}\Biggl\}$$
It is possible to transform this 
to:
$$\begin{pmatrix}-6 \\\ -1 \\\ 1 \\\ -4\end{pmatrix}+Span\Biggl\{\begin{pmatrix}13 \\\ 25 \\\ -2 \\\ -1\end{pmatrix}\Biggl\}$$
by multiplying the generator by $-4$ and adding it to the particular solution of the system.

As you can see, in the process of the transformation the span generator has changed a sign. Is that necessary? After all, the span should be closed under scalar multiplication, so why explicitly state the sign change?

Answer (score 0):

After further research, the answer to the question is that it does not matter if the span generator changed sign, as we can multiply by $-1$ as many time as we want, since the span is closed under scalar multiplication.